# Extracting (and modifying) all words from text that begin with a specific string?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays

I am looking for a more efficient way to select words from a block of text that begin with a specific string.  I'd also like to modify them at the same time if possible.  In my case, I am looking to find hashtags and downcase them, so given a string:

```
the quick brown #Fox jumps over the lazy #dog
```

I'd like to produce the array:

```
["#fox","#dog"]
```

or even:

```
["fox","dog"]
```

My (presumably inefficient) code at present looks like this:

```
words = item.body.split(" ")
tagged_words = words.select{|x| x[0,1] == "#"}
tagged_words = tagged_words.map{ |x| x.downcase }
```

I assume the first two lines can be replaced with a regex, but could not figure it out.  Perhaps there is even a way to combine all three lines of code?

This part is perhaps less relevant to the masses, but what I ultimately want to do is take a full list of tags and reduce it to only tags not referenced within the item body. This requires one more line of code, so extra thanks for anyone that can rewrite the entire process to be more efficient.

```
external_tags = item.tags.select{|tag| !tagged_words.include?("#"+tag.name)}
```

I searched for a while for an answer to the first part of my question, but could not find one.  Any response/comment referencing an answer to my more general question would certainly suffice.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "the quick brown #Fox jumps over the lazy #dog"
p s.scan(/(^|\s)#(\S+)/).map { |m| m[1].downcase }
# => ["fox", "dog"]
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you've already answered the second part of the question once this part is working.

Answer (score 1):

To grab just the tags:

```
'the quick brown #Fox jumps over the lazy #dog'.scan(/#\S+/)
# => ["#Fox", "#dog"]
```

If you don't want the hash marks:

```
'the quick brown #Fox jumps over the lazy #dog'.scan(/(?<=#)\S+/)
# => ["Fox", "dog"]
```

Which uses a look-behind to match but not capture "`#`" characters.

Or:

```
'the quick brown #Fox jumps over the lazy #dog'.scan(/#\S+/).map{ |s| s.tr('#', '') }
# => ["Fox", "dog"]
```

Or:

```
'the quick brown #Fox jumps over the lazy #dog'.scan(/#\S+/).map{ |s| s.delete('#') }
# => ["Fox", "dog"]
```

Or:

```
'the quick brown #Fox jumps over the lazy #dog'.scan(/#\S+/).map{ |s| s.sub('#', '') }
# => ["Fox", "dog"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tag_string = "the quick brown #Fox jumps over the lazy #dog"
tag_string.split(" ").select{|a| /^#/.match(a)}.map(&:downcase)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? ([Positive lookbehind](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors))

```
str = "the quick brown #Fox jumps over the lazy #dog"
str.scan(/#\w+/)
=> ["#Fox", "#dog"]

# using Positive lookbehind 
str.scan(/(?<=#)\w+/)
=> ["Fox", "dog"]

str.scan(/(?<=#)\w+/).map(&:downcase)
=> ["fox", "dog"]
```

Comment: Don't use a capture in the `scan` pattern and you won't get arrays of arrays, which will avoid having to `flatten` the output.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for the suggestion! It looks much better now :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about word chars and word boundaries:

```
"the quick brown #Fox jumps over the lazy #dog".scan /\B#\w+\b/
#=> ["#Fox", "#dog"]
```

Do yourself a favor and [learn all about them](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html).